# how to show selected item(s) details (Title & Cost) into another activity , like:- Shopping Cart Functinality (Add to Cart & View Cart)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, android-listview

i am making an app, in which i am fetching data into listview using json parser, then showing selected listview item row into another activity with item details (Note:- Details i am fetching from ListView Activity to singleItem Activity) now i need to show Item Title and Cost for all the selected items into another activity i.e.- ViewCart (from singleItem Activity to ViewCart Activity)by using Add to Cart button on singleItem activity to send all selected records into ViewCart activity like:- Shopping Cart functionality Add to Cart then view selected records in a whole into another activity ViewCart, and i just want to show selected item's Title and Cost to another activity, still i am showing only the one selected item not all the selected item(s) by user in a session, and i am also not saving that record for complete session, but now i want to show all selected items by user into viewcart activity based on complete session.
below i am placing singleItem and ViewCart Code:-

SingleItem Code:-

```
    public class SingleMenuItem extends Activity{
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "imageUri";
private EditText edit_qty_code;
private TextView txt_total;
private TextView text_cost_code;
private double itemamount = 0;
private double itemquantity = 0;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single);

    Intent in = getIntent();
    String title = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
    String thumb_url = in.getStringExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL);
    String cost = in.getStringExtra(KEY_COST);

    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());

    ImageView imgv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.single_thumb);
    TextView txttitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.single_title);
    TextView txtcost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.single_cost);
    TextView txtheader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.actionbar);

    txttitle.setText(title);
    txtheader.setText(title);
    txtcost.setText(cost);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(thumb_url, imgv);

    text_cost_code = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.single_cost);
    edit_qty_code = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.single_qty);
    txt_total=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.single_total);

    itemamount=Double.parseDouble(text_cost_code.getText().toString());
    txt_total.setText(Double.toString(itemamount));

    edit_qty_code.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
    int after) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         itemquantity=Double.parseDouble(edit_qty_code.getText().toString());
         itemamount=Double.parseDouble(text_cost_code.getText().toString());
         txt_total.setText(Double.toString(itemquantity*itemamount));
    }
    });             

    ImageButton addToCartButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_add);
    addToCartButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {    

        Intent in = new Intent
           (SingleMenuItem.this, com.erachnida.restaurant.versionoct.FinalOrder.class);
        in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE)); 
        in.putExtra(KEY_COST, getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_COST));
        startActivity(in);

            // Close the activity
            //  finish();
        }
    });    
}}
```

ViewCart Code:-

```
public class FinalOrder extends Activity
{
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view);     


    Intent in = getIntent();

    String title1 = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
    String cost1 = in.getStringExtra(KEY_COST);

    TextView txttitle1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    TextView txtcost1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_cost);

    txttitle1.setText(title1);
    txtcost1.setText(cost1);    

}
}
```

Comment: First note: You are passing strings through the extras object, I would try to gather all the information into one Object e.g. "ShopItem". If you implement the parceable interface on ShopItem then you can pass that object through activities
Second note: Somewhere in your code you need to persist the data from your cart. you need to "save" it somewhere. For this you can use sharedpreferences, sqllite db or a file on client side.

Comment: user1281750 i agree, could you please write some code for me, how to show selected items into another activity, here i am using imagebutton click once user will click on that, i want show Title and Cost for the selected item into another activity like viewcart

Comment: Are you using a listview to show the data? are you using checkboxes in this listview?

Comment: sorry for the late response, i am using listview once user will click on any of the listview item row then showing that selected item in a whole, along with Add to Cart button, here i want whenever user will click on that button show item details(only name and cost) to vieworder form

Answer (score 0):

Remove your onclick code with below code.

```
 public void onClick(View v) {    

    Intent in = new Intent
       (SingleMenuItem.this, com.erachnida.restaurant.versionoct.FinalOrder.class);
    in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, title); 
    in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
    startActivity(in);

        // Close the activity
        //  finish();
    }
```